# how to encrypt web chat URL token and User Id to avoid missus of my bot

Tags: botframework

I am using web chat for my bot application, but here I have security issue with URL.
If someone copies below url, he will be able to change userID and and name 
than he can chat with my bot with name of other person.

So I want to encrypt this URL token and user id to avoid change user ID.

> https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/YOUR_BOT_ID?s=YOUR_BOT_SECRET&username=DESIRED_USERNAME&userid=DESIRED_USERID

Answer (score 4):

There are several things pointed in your question that you should modify.

---

### Use Token instead of Secret:

To avoid misuse of a webchat, you must not use the `secret` in the URL but generate a `token` and use this token in the URL.

How to do this?

To exchange your secret for a token and generate the embed:

1. Issue a **GET** request to `https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens` and pass your web chat secret via the `Authorization` header.
2. The response to your **GET** request will contain the token (surrounded with quotation marks) that can be used to start a conversation by rendering the web chat control within an iframe. A token is valid for one conversation only; to start another conversation, you must generate a new token.
3. Within the `iframe` **Embed code** that you copied from the Web Chat channel within the Bot Framework Portal (as described in Step 1 above), change the `s=` parameter to `t=` and replace `YOUR_SECRET_HERE` with your token.

So at the end your URL will look like:

```
https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/YOUR_BOT_ID?t=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE&...
```

Everything is explained with more details in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/channel-connect-webchat?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)

---

### Passing values

If you want to avoid an user to change the settings you are passing in `username` and `userid`, you are free to encrypt / hash / whatever you want those fields and implement your decrypt / dehash logic on your bot side to get the interesting value